# Product show in search suggestion after delete

Tags: magento-1.9

I delete all products in magento but when i search deleted product name in seachbox it still shows.
[image]

I have taken these steps after product deletion:

```
Re-Index Site
Clear Cache
```

Comment: try in private browser window once....

Answer (score 0):

Please delete your `var/cache` folder and also `flush cache storage` from admin.
and try again and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted Search Terms and now works fine.

Answer (score -1):

go to admin panel > stores > configuration > mageplaza extension > search > general > choose Reindex search database (manually) > Reindex Search data