# magento 2.3 why the deleted products still show at the dropdown of search box

Tags: product, magento2.3, catalogsearch

I am using magento2.3 and porto theme
why the deleted products still show at the dropdown of search box
[image]

I have cleared all cache ,and clicked the following 5 cache:"Flush Magento Cache,Flush Cache Storage,
Flush Catalog Images Cache 
Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache
Flush Static Files Cache
and bin/magento indexer:reindex

and I have also deleted all "search items" and rm -r /var/cache as [Product show in search suggestion after delete](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133187/product-show-in-search-suggestion-after-delete) said.

but not work for me

what should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome, have you reindexed successfully after deleting the product also are you using any other 3rd party search extensions which could be causing the issue. if  you have done all of these id suggest removing all the files from pub/static/ generation/ var/view_processed/ and redeploying the static content

Comment: thanks for reply,by the way,1)I have gone to root directory to execute "bin/magento indexer:reindex" 2) do you mean I also need to go to root directory to execute "rm -r pub/static/ 
rm -r generation/ 
rm -r var/view_processed/ 

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f" ?

Comment: If you have reindexed and you still have the issue then go to the magento root and run "rm -r pub/static/ generation/ var/" that should have same action without reperative rm -rf and then once you have done that redeploy your content also rememember to deploy additional languages e.g. en_GB de_DE